# jQuery not running with the html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are enough and more questions on this topic, but none of them seem to fix up my problem. I am new to jquery and was trying it out for my code. It just doesn't seem to get up and running. I have tried changing the order in which the script occurs with other scripts, I have checked for the directory in which my jquery file resides, I have tried to use both the CDN version and the downloadable one. Nothing seems to work.

this is the head of my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

            <title>Draft1</title>


            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="./css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
            <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
                      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" >
            <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


            <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>

        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>



        <![endif]-->
     </head>
```

i have put jquery at the end of the body of my html

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
            <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.3"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready((function) {

                $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
            });
        </script>


            <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In this code I have put the jquery code with the html code itself. I have tried another version by putting the code in a separate file and running it, that doesnt work either.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: have a look at the javascript console. Itll probably say `$ is not defined`

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  When you use the browser's debugging tools, what happens?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When the browser requests the JavaScript file(s), what is the response?  When you debug, does the code execute at all?  How specifically does it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

1. Change `<script src="./js/jquery-1.11.3"></script>` to `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>`
2. Change `$(document).ready((function) {` to `$(function(){` or `$(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a typo where you add the jquery tag. the file name should end in the extension `.js` so probably something like this:

```
<script src="./js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery script src is missing the .js extension

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put jQuery in the head

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Draft1</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="./css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
                  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" >
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready((function) {

            $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
        });
    </script>
    </head>
```